# Copy/Paste HTML5 canvas(es)

Tags: html, canvas

I have a graphing application that overlays several canvases. I'd like the user to be able to right-click and save image. When the user does this now, it only saves the top layer canvas (correctly), but misses the lower layers. What might a strategy be to composite the multiple canvases when the right-click occurs?

Thank you,

PT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strategy would be, to draw all the lower canvases on the top canvas, when a user right clicks on the top canvas to save image.

You could use **[`drawImage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage)** method, to draw a certain canvas on another canvas.

Here is a quick example, showing how this could be done ...

```js
var lowerCTX = document.querySelector('#lowerCanvas').getContext('2d');
var upperCTX = document.querySelector('#upperCanvas').getContext('2d');

//draw rect on lower canvas
lowerCTX.fillStyle = 'green';
lowerCTX.fillRect(20, 20, 50, 50);

//draw rect on upper canvas
upperCTX.fillStyle = 'red';
upperCTX.fillRect(130, 130, 50, 50);

//add right click event to upper canvas
upperCTX.canvas.onmousedown = function(e) {
   if (e.which === 3) {
      //draw lower canvas on upper canvas
      upperCTX.drawImage(lowerCTX.canvas, 0, 0);
   }
};
```

```css
body{margin:10px 0 0 0;overflow:hidden}#canvas_wrapper{display: inline-flex}canvas{border: 1px solid #ccc}#upperCanvas{margin-left: -202px}
```

```html
<div id="canvas_wrapper">
    <canvas id="lowerCanvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
    <canvas id="upperCanvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Very nice. One thing tho, the image gets darker on the copy because compositing. How do I erase the top level image when the context menu disappears? I couldn't find a "context menu closed" event?